# 0002: You do not have permissions to make this API call

Tags: paypal, connector

Here is an example of the Paypal connector using an address-verify call that is failing in sandbox environment.

We're getting error `"You do not have permissions to make this API call"`. We're using paypal Mulesoft connector to verify address and make payment. Could you please take a look and let us know how to make it wor?

Paypal business account email address: nileshk.jain-facilitator@gmail.com. We are getting same error when trying to call other functions like Authorize, Do direct payment, refund etc..

**SOAP Request:**

`<soap:Envelope [link removed]><soap:Header><ns2:RequesterCredentials xmlns:ns3="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><Credentials><Username>[link removed]</Username><Password>1369269276</Password><Signature>AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AjYiSzqYGmMwbexuKiaJ.l.4vel4</Signature></Credentials></ns2:RequesterCredentials></soap:Header><soap:Body><ns2:AddressVerifyReq xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ns3="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"><ns2:AddressVerifyRequest><Version>98.0</Version><ns2:Email>[link removed]</ns2:Email><ns2:Street>test</ns2:Street><ns2:Zip>test</ns2:Zip></ns2:AddressVerifyRequest></ns2:AddressVerifyReq></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`

**SOAP Response:**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope [link removed] [link removed] [link removed] [link removed] [link removed] xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" [link removed] xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" [link removed] [link removed] xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><SOAP-ENV:Header><Security [link removed] xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security><RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType"><Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType"><Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username><Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password><Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature><Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject></Credentials></RequesterCredentials></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0"><AddressVerifyResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2013-05-23T21:31:13Z</Timestamp><Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack><CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">db6273f7185de</CorrelationID><Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType"><ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Authentication/Authorization Failed</ShortMessage><LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">You do not have permissions to make this API call</LongMessage><ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10002</ErrorCode><SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode></Errors><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">98.0</Version><Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">5908853</Build><ConfirmationCode xsi:type="ebl:AddressStatusCodeType">None</ConfirmationCode><StreetMatch xsi:type="ebl:MatchStatusCodeType">None</StreetMatch><ZipMatch xsi:type="ebl:MatchStatusCodeType">None</ZipMatch></AddressVerifyResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

AddressVerify is an API that is not enabled by default.  I have gone ahead and enabled this on your account.  Try testing with it now, you should be able to make the API call successfully now.

Comment: Thanks for your help !!!. I'm still seeing this issue. How much time does it take for changes to be available on Sandbox? Also, is it possible to enable other functions like Do Direct payment, Refund etc for given account. We're creating a subscription solution and need to call these functions.

Comment: Hi, I'm able to hit verifyaddress function but getting error when trying to hit DoDirectPayment.ERROR 2013-05-30 15:46:04,093 [[paypalflow].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
Message: Failed to invoke doDirectPayment. Message payload is of type: String
Code: MULE_ERROR--2
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException) java.lang.Class:-2 (null)
2. Failed to invoke doDirectPayment. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
org.mule.module.paypal.processors.DoDirectPaymentMessageProcessor:177

Comment: Chad could you set allow addressverify for my sandbox account?  canderson-facilitator@dkssystems.com